# Drop zeroes from xarray DataArray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a DataArray with three coordinates and I wanted to drop arrays containing all zeroes from one of the dimensions, but I can't seem to get it right. The data array (old_array) looks as follows, and as you can see there are quite a few arrays that are filled with zeroes.

```
<xarray.DataArray (dim1: 100, dim2: 100, dim3: 100)>
array([[[81.20, 13.20, 12.24, ..., 81.24,
         14.61, 85.58],
        [31.34, 83.96, 02.97, ..., 46.88,
         01.81, 48.24],
        [43.54, 12.50, 35.33, ..., 39.23,
         91.93, 01.21],
        [37.95, 75.59, 71.00, ..., 15.14,
         68.76, 44.56],
        [54.31, 48.99, 85.59, ..., 15.58,
         86.48, 81.19]],

       [[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
...                                
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ]],           
                                   
       [[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ],            
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  0.  ,
          0.  ,  0.  ]]])
Coordinates:
  * dim1  (dim1) <U7 'x0 y0 z0' 'x1 y0 z0' 'x2 y0 z0' ... 'x10 y10 z8' 'x10 y10 z9' 'x10 y10 z10'
  * dim2  (dim2) float64 0.0 0.1 0.2 ... 9.8 9.9 10.0
  * dim3  (dim3) float64 0.5 1.0 1.5 ... 49.0 49.5 50.0
```

I tried

```
new_array = old_array.drop_sel(dim1 = np.zeros(100))
```

But it gives me KeyError: "not all values found in index 'dim1'"

I also tried

```
new_array = old_array.drop(np.zeros(100), dim1)
```

But then I have a ValueError: dimension 'x1 y5 z3' does not have coordinate labels.

I wanted to tell xarray "If 'x2 y3 z7' is an array with all zeroes, then delete it", but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to get useful feedback here. Can you provide a complete example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its still a little hard to tell what you are trying to do but from what I can tell, you want to drop parts of the array that are equal to zero. For that you should use `DataArray.where` with `drop=True`:

```
old_array.where(old_array > 0, drop=True)
```

`drop_sel` is used to drop index labels based on their value.